# How to handle "docker-in-docker" problem when using Jenkins inside K8S

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm

New to Kubernetes, a little complex question needs help.

### Background

1. Using Jenkins in GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine)
2. Want to use `jenkins-docker` plugin to provide the specific test environment for each type of tests
3. Don't want to mixin `docker` binary in the Jenkins image (because it is large)
4. Don't want `docker-in-docker`

   1. More specifically, I don't want the Jenkins Pod be a new Docker Server

### What I want

1. Each test environment can create a new pod in GKE Cluster, rather than creating containers inside the Jenkins Pod

### P.S.

I have just read some articles, but half of them are telling about "how to use K8S to scale up the Jenkins (using jenkins-slave + jenkins-kubernates plugin)", another half are telling about how to "use docker plugin in a dockerized jenkins container on a bare metal machine (you can use `/var/run/docker.sock` to communicate between the host and the docker container)**", but I cannot find **how to use docker plugin (to provide a specific environment) in a dockerized jenkins container inside K8S**

Comment: Not sure if there is a plugin for that. As an alternative you can create the corresponding YAML files for the pods / deployments that you want to create and then use the jenkins agent to create them with `kubectl apply`.